Reference for facts used in Bloch, "Algebraic cycles and L-functions II"
The proof of lemma 1.1 in [1] does not give references for a few statements it uses.
In the setting of the proof, $X$ is a smooth projective variety over a number field $k$ with a fixed embedding to $\mathbb{C}$, $Y$ is a closed subscheme (no further regularity assumptions stated on $Y$, though perhaps we can take it to be reduced) of dimension $d$ of $X_\mathbb{C}$. $Z \subset Y$ is a closed subscheme containing the singular points of $Y$ (I think it is implicit that $Z$ should be of pure codimension 1). There are two isomorphic exact sequences,
\begin{gather*}
H_{2d-1}(Y, Z; \mathbb{Z}) \to H_{2d-2}(Z; \mathbb{Z}) \to H_{2d-2}(Y; \mathbb{Z}) \\
H^1(Y-Z; \mathbb{Z}) \to \bigoplus_{\textrm{components of } Z} \mathbb{Z} \to H_{2d-2}(Y; \mathbb{Z}).
\end{gather*}
Let $c$ be a $(d-1)$-cycle in $X$, supported on $Y$ and homologous to zero in $Y$. Bloch indicates that $c$ is determined up to algebraic equivalence in $X$ by its image in $H_{2d-2}(Z; \mathbb{Z})$ under some map (which map is not explicitly stated). I would like a reference for the statement Bloch is using.
My goal is to instead consider the case where $X$ is a smooth projective variety over an arbitrary field $k$ and $Y$ is a closed subscheme of $X_{\overline{k}}$, and run Bloch's proof with singular (co)homology replaced by $\ell$-adic cohomology (I don't care about torsion and am willing to assume resolution of singularities). I don't foresee a problem with this strategy, but I just need to understand the one claim I mentioned. Thanks for any help.
References:
[1] Bloch, S. (1985). Algebraic cycles and values of L-functions II. In Duke Mathematical Journal (Vol. 52, Issue 2). Duke University Press. https://doi.org/10.1215/s0012-7094-85-05219-6
